# Positive information counterexample

Tags: probability

An event F is said to carry positive information about an event E ($F\to E$) if $P[E|F]\ge P[E]$

Prove or give counterexample to the following assertion: if $F\to E$ then $E\to F$

My attempt: I think that it is true:

By hypothesis we have that $F\to E$ : $P[E|F]={P[F|E]P(E)\over P(F)}\ge P(E)$ then we have that $P[F|E]\ge P[F]$ hence $F\to E$

the thing is that my friend told me that this statement is false, so can´t think of any counterexample, Can you help me please? I would realy appreciate it :)

Comment: I would rather call the information 'non-negative'.

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1138373/events-that-carry-negative-information

Answer (score 3):

The relation ($F$ carries positive information about $E$) can also be expressed by: $$P\left(E\cap F\right)\geq P\left(E\right)P\left(F\right)$$

In this form it is evident that the relation is symmetric.