# Events that carry negative information

Tags: probability, proof-verification, proof-writing

I want to answer the following exercise:

An event $F$ is said to carry negative information about an event $E$, and we write $F \downarrow E$ if $P(E|F) \le P(E)$

Prove or give counterexamples of the following assertions:

a) If $F \downarrow E$ then $E \downarrow F$

my attempt: we have that $\frac{P(EF)}{P(F)} \leq P(E)$ then we have that $P(FE)=P(EF) \leq P(E)P(F)$ therefore $\frac{P(FE)}{P(E)} \leq P(F)$

b)If $F \downarrow E$ and $E \downarrow G$ then $F \downarrow G$

c)If $F \downarrow E$ and $G \downarrow E$ then $FG \downarrow E$

Repaeat a),b),c) but with $\uparrow$(is the same definition but with greater than instead of lower than)

and my questions are, Am I right in my attempt?, I can't figure out how in b) I will get $P(GF)$, and if I am wrong how can I get the counterexamples for a),b),c) I think that the same way to proceed with $\downarrow$ is equal to $\uparrow$,then if I have the $\downarrow$ part the other one is equal only the inequalities are inverted,isn't?

Thanks a lot for your help, I appreciate it very much :)

Answer (score 2):

**Hint(s):**

For part (b), what happens if $G=F$?

For part (c), what if $F$ and $G$ are events where $F \downarrow G$, and $E$ is the event 
$$E = (F \text{ and } G) \text{ or } (\text{not }F \text{ and not } G)$$
(Try drawing a Venn Diagram if you're having trouble seeing what I'm describing.  $F$ and $G$ should be two ovals with a small intersection relative to their sizes, and $E$ should be the area both outside the two ovals and inside their intersection).

Comment: tahnks a lot for the help :) but I don't understand the hint of part c)

Comment: will this work for $\uparrow$?

Comment: thanks for the edit, and well I see that $E=(F \cap G)\cup (F^c \cap G^c)$ right?

Comment: Yup.  Can you compute $P(E), P(E|F), P(E|G), and P(E|F\cap G)$ (possibly giving exact values of $P(F)$, $P(G)$, and $P(F\cap G)$)?

Comment: then when I give the values I will get in a contradiction ?

Comment: Yes, you will get a contradiction.

Comment: Am I right in my attempt of a)?

Comment: Your work on (a) looks solid to me.

Comment: thanks a lot ;), and will this work for $\uparrow$?

Comment: I got it, in the first one you get that $\frac{P(F)}{P(F)} \leq P(F)$ right? and in c) you get that $P(FGE)=P(FG)$ but that means that $1\le P(E)$ and contradiction, Am I right?

Comment: How do you prove $F \downarrow E$ and $G \downarrow E$ ? I'm stuck with these. :(.

Answer (score 2):

Inspired by user88319. I can give a counterexample of (c).

Suppose S = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14},

E = {get a point >= 7},

F = {1, 2, 3, 7},

G = {4, 5, 6, 7},

P(E) = 8/14,

P(E|F) = 1/4 < P(E),

P(E|G) = 1/4 < P(E),

But P(E|GF) = 1 > P(E) because the only situation that F and G both happen is get point 7