# Give counterexamples of some assertions in probability

Tags: probability, proof-writing

I have the following exercise:

An event $F$ is said to carry positive information about an event $E$, and we write $F \uparrow E$ if $P(E|F) \ge P(E)$

Prove or give counterexamples of the following assertions:

a) If $F \uparrow E$ then $E \uparrow F$

b)If $F \uparrow E$ and $E \uparrow G$ then $F \uparrow G$

c)If $F \uparrow E$ and $G \uparrow E$ then $FG \uparrow E$

the first one I have already proved it, but I don't know which counterexamples take in b) and c), because the ones that I gave but in the case of $\downarrow$ don`t work for this case, Can someone help me please :)? I appreciate it, thanks a lot in advance

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1138373/events-that-carry-negative-information