# Probability negative information

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

I there, about this exercise:

An event F is said to carry negative information
about an event E, and we write $F\rightarrow E$ if $P(E|F)\leq P(E)$

Prove or give a counter example for the following claim:

If $F\rightarrow E$ then $E \rightarrow F $

Well, my attempt was:

$$
P(E|F) = \frac{P(E \cap F)}{P(F)} \leq P(E)  => P(E \cap F)\geq P(E)*P(F)
$$

$$
P(F|E) = \frac{P(F \cap E)}{P(E)} \leq P(F)  => P(F \cap E)\geq P(F)*P(E)
$$

And since $ P(F \cap E) = P(E \cap F) $
Than it seems pretty correct to me! (but the solution manual says I'm wrong).

What is wrong in my way of thinking?
Thanks!

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1138373/events-that-carry-negative-information

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The $\geq$ signs in your attempt should be $\leq$ signs.

That's all I can find.

Further the idea is okay.

If both sides are multiplied by factor $P(F)$ then $P(E\mid F)\leq P(E)$ changes into: $$P(E\cap F)\leq P(E)P(F)$$and it is immediate then that the relation is symmetric.

Comment: Thanks but the fact that $P(F) \leq 1$ doesn't flip the sign when multiplying?

Comment: No, positive numbers do not flip the sign. Negative numbers do.

Comment: Yes, foolish me :) Anyway, @drhab do you think it's a mistake in the manual?

Comment: If the manual is rejecting this proof then: yes, the manual is wrong.