# How does this assumption disprove this "carry-negative" claim?

Tags: probability

> Let us define F carries negative information for E if and only if $P(E| F) <= P(E)$.
>
> Prove or disprove this claim: If $F \downarrow$ $E$ and $G \downarrow E$ then $FG \downarrow E$

The original idea comes from [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1138373/events-that-carry-negative-information)(**user88319**'s answer) and I'll restate it:

Let $E = FG \cup F^cG^c$ and assume that $F \downarrow G$. My question is: Why does this disprove the claim? I've tried to check whether or not $F \downarrow E$ is true but my reasoning goes nowhere:

$F \downarrow E \iff P(E|F) \leq P(E)$. So from here, I tried to evaluate $P(E | F)$.

$$P(E | F) = \frac{P(EF)}{P(F)} = \frac{P(FG)}{P(F)} = P(G | F)$$. We know that $F \downarrow G$, or equivalently, $P(G | F) \leq P(G)$. So: $P(E | F) \leq P(G)$, which is not something we want.  There's some hope, though. If indeed, $F \downarrow E$ and $G \downarrow E$ are true, then we can choose a counter-example in which $P(E) < 1$ so that:
$$FG \downarrow E \iff (P(E | FG) = 1) \leq P(E)$$, can't be true and thus disprove the whole thing.

The only point that makes me stuck is that: How does this choice of condition on $E, F, G$ make $F \downarrow E$ and $G \downarrow E$? Thank you for reading