# Prove claims related to positive-carry events?

Tags: probability

Let me first state the problem:

> Let us define F carries positive information for E if and only if $P(E| F) \geq P(E)$.
>
> Prove or disprove these claims:
> a. If $F \uparrow E$ and $E \uparrow G$, then $F \uparrow G$
> b. If $F \uparrow$ $E$ and $G \uparrow E$ then $FG \uparrow E$

This problem makes me really stuck. There's another version of this question asked [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1138373/events-that-carry-negative-information), which contains the "negative-carry" version of this.

Back to the problem, I want to mimic the approach in the above link but can't. My attempt for b is to try $F$ and $F^c$, but failed. In fact, $F \uparrow E $ does not imply $F^c | E$. My temptation is to use $F \uparrow F^c \iff P(F) \leq 0$ to disprove b.

Any hint for me to work this out? I'm super stuck at this. :(

Comment: "Temptation" is a word that means something very different from "attempt" (which means to try something). For example, a husband my have temptation to cheat on his wife with his secretary. Maybe you did intend to use temptation, but I would suggest using "want" instead, as in "I want to use $F \uparrow F^c$..." Anyway, returning to maths, does $F \uparrow E$ means $P(E \mid F) \geq P(E)$ or is it $E \uparrow F$ that means that?

Comment: @WilliamM They're interchangable. We can prove that.

Comment: Seems better to think on the symmetric relationship $F \uparrow E$ if and only if $P(E \cap F) \geq P(E) P(F).$ Note that if one event is contained in the other, then they carry positive information about the other. For a., consider $F$ and $G$ disjoint and $E = F \cup G.$ For b., modify a.'s example a little.